# Different ways to initialize Plotly's Scattergeo fig and one won't allow me to "update_geos" and the other I can't add data

Tags: python, json, plot, plotly

I'm new to using Plotly but after a few tutorials I decided I wanted to start my own project that looks at companies carbon footprints. I configured my own JSON data and created a Scattergeo plot with the data I wanted. The issue came when I wanted to change the borders from continents to countries and to change it to an orthographic view. From the Plotly website I found the line that would do that: `fig.update_geos(projection_type="orthographic, showcountries=True")`

My issue came when I added that code, I then got the error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_geos'`

I then realized that the way I was doing it and the way it was displayed on the Plotly website was different. I created my visualisation by first importing like this: `from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout` and `from plotly import offline`. All Plotly did was the line: `import plotly.graph_objects as go`.

I defined my data by writing code like this in a dictionary: `data = [{}]` and defining my layout as `my_layout = Layout(title='How you measure up: Companies')` and then creating the fig `fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}`.

On the website the code was simply written as `fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())` which initialized the visualization and everything.

Evidently I learnt a different method than used by Plotly. I've tried mixing my code in a few different ways to combine Plotly's code and mine. I'm hoping that you guys might be able to help me either change my own code to allow for the `fig.update_geos` statement or to point me towards a tutorial or solution where I can learn how to add my own data to Plotly's solution.

**I'm attaching mine and Plotly's code below here in case anyone wants to have a look, I hope the question described my issue but I figured it might help even though it's a bit long.**

**My Code; I don't know how to update it visually or change it to orthographic view.**

```
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

filename = 'compPrint1.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    all_json_data = json.load(f)

readable_file = 'readable_json_data.json'
with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_json_data, f, indent=4)

#  cfp = Carbon FootPrint
companies, cfp, locations, lats, longs = [], [], [], [], []
for json_data in all_json_data:
    company = json_data['company']
    cp = json_data['carbonprint']
    location = json_data['location']
    lat = json_data['Latitude']
    long = json_data['Longitude']
    companies.append(company)
    cfp.append(cp)
    locations.append(location)
    lats.append(lat)
    longs.append(long)

companycfp = []
for json_data in all_json_data:
    comp = json_data['company']
    fp = json_data['carbonprint']
    stringfp = str(fp)
    compfp = f'{comp}, {stringfp} Million Metric Tons'
    companycfp.append(compfp)

data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': longs,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': companycfp,
    'marker': {
        'size': [0.4*cp for cp in cfp],
        'color': cfp,
        'colorscale': 'fall',
    },
}]

my_layout = Layout(title='How you measure up: Companies')

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}

offline.plot(fig)
```

**Plotly Website Code; I don't know how to add my above data to this visual.**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())
fig.update_geos(projection_type="orthographic")
fig.update_layout(height=300, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Thanks so much for any help! Sorry for the fairly long post. When it comes to things I've tried it hasn't been much. I haven't been able to find many tutorials concerning my situation and so far mix and matching my code hasn't worked very well.

Comment: a couple of observations 1) `readable_file = 'readable_json_data.json'
with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_json_data, f, indent=4)
` effectively does nothing.  opening a file to then format another **dict** as indented for no functional purpose.  2) you are working hard manipulating **dict** / JSON for what would be straight forward with **pandas**.  Any reason for this?   3) where can I source the JSON from that you are working with?

Comment: 1) Good to know, I don't necessarily know why I was doing that myself, the tutorial I followed included that code but didn't explain it very much so I just assumed it was necessary for some reason. 2) Similar to the first part, I learnt more about JSON data and not a ton about Pandas so I just followed through with using that, I'll do more research into learning Pandas because as I learn more it sounds much more efficient. 3) I created my own JSON file from scratch to fit my data, I could share that here somehow but there's no file currently I can link to as it's my own data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- getting your code to run,  I have manipulated some same data to be what I can tell is same shape as your data
- from this - it appears you are doing a lot of unnecessary heavy lifting. Use **Plotly Express**.  Prerequisite is get your data into a dataframe.  I believe this is just use the constructor.
- then overall solution becomes very simple

#### solution

```
import plotly.express as px

px.scatter_geo(
    pd.DataFrame(all_json_data),
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    color="carbonprint",
    hover_data={"company": True, "carbonprint": ":.2f"},
).update_layout(geo={"projection":{"type":"orthographic"}})
```

#### making your code work

```
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# filename = 'compPrint1.json'
# with open(filename) as f:
#     all_json_data = json.load(f)

# readable_file = 'readable_json_data.json'
# with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
#     json.dump(all_json_data, f, indent=4)
all_json_data = {}
df2 = pd.read_html("https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-235-15.html")[0].rename(
    columns={"Latitude": "Lat", "Longitude": "Lon"}
)
df2 = df2.rename(
    columns={"Place Name": "company", "Lat": "Latitude", "Lon": "Longitude"}
).assign(carbonprint=np.random.uniform(1, 4, len(df2)), location=df2["Place Name"])
all_json_data = df2.to_dict("records")

#  cfp = Carbon FootPrint
companies, cfp, locations, lats, longs = [], [], [], [], []
for json_data in all_json_data:
    company = json_data["company"]
    cp = json_data["carbonprint"]
    location = json_data["location"]
    lat = json_data["Latitude"]
    long = json_data["Longitude"]
    companies.append(company)
    cfp.append(cp)
    locations.append(location)
    lats.append(lat)
    longs.append(long)

companycfp = []
for json_data in all_json_data:
    comp = json_data["company"]
    fp = json_data["carbonprint"]
    stringfp = str(fp)
    compfp = f"{comp}, {stringfp} Million Metric Tons"
    companycfp.append(compfp)

data = [
    {
        "type": "scattergeo",
        "lon": longs,
        "lat": lats,
        "text": companycfp,
        "marker": {
            "size": [0.4 * cp for cp in cfp],
            "color": cfp,
            "colorscale": "fall",
        },
    }
]

my_layout = Layout(title="How you measure up: Companies")

fig = {"data": data, "layout": my_layout}

# offline.plot(fig)
go.Figure(fig)
```

Comment: Thank you for that response that's super helpful. I'll learn more about Pandas as it sounds like a much better and more efficient way to organize my data.